# multidimensional array unset not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my array;

```
var_dump($contact['poco']['tags']);

array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'boy' (length=3)
      'color' => string '#332409' (length=7)
      'id' => string '57160583b0e6df19598b4568' (length=24)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'girl' (length=4)
      'color' => string '#2e2f15' (length=7)
      'id' => string '57160589b0e6df1d598b4567' (length=24)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'zebra' (length=5)
      'color' => string '#646604' (length=7)
      'id' => string '57160592b0e6df7b588b4567' (length=24)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'potential duplicate' (length=19)
      'color' => string '#f00' (length=4)
      'id' => string '57161d9db0e6df0f5c8b456b' (length=24)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'no phone numbers' (length=16)
      'color' => string '#5833d2' (length=7)
      'id' => string '5716059ab0e6df7b588b456d' (length=24)
```

I just want to unset/remove one that have the following tags;

```
$smartTags = ['potential duplicate', 'no emails', 'no phone numbers'];
```

So I end up with;

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'boy' (length=3)
      'color' => string '#332409' (length=7)
      'id' => string '57160583b0e6df19598b4568' (length=24)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'girl' (length=4)
      'color' => string '#2e2f15' (length=7)
      'id' => string '57160589b0e6df1d598b4567' (length=24)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'zebra' (length=5)
      'color' => string '#646604' (length=7)
      'id' => string '57160592b0e6df7b588b4567' (length=24)
```

I have tried;

```
$smartTags = ['potential duplicate', 'no emails', 'no phone numbers'];

foreach ($contact['poco']['tags'] as $key => $tag) {

    if (in_array($tag, $smartTags)) {
        unset($contact['poco']['tags'][$key]);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't do anything. I might be having trouble because of the multi-dimensionalness of this array...

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: `if (in_array($tag['tag'], $smartTags)) {`

Comment: your condition not true....

Comment: @splash58 - thanks. it works. sometimes just a second pair of eyes help

Answer (score 0):

Try up with this.

```
foreach ($contact['poco']['tags'] as $key => $tag) {        
    if (in_array($tag['tag'], $smartTags)) {
        unset($contact['poco']['tags'][$key]);
    }    
}
```